# How to show/hide ng4-spinner-loader on model only angular 4/6/7?

Tags: angular6, spinner, loader

I want to show a loader on pop-up/model once a HTTP request triggers and hide it when all http requests are completed.

I am new to angular and I am not able to find a way to implement it.

My `app.html`:

```
 <ng4-loading-spinner [threshold]="2000" [template]="template" [loadingText]="'Please wait...'" [zIndex]="9999"> </ng4-loading-spinner>

app.ts
this.spinnerService.show();
```

I am using `import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope. If the request is inside of a component or will be called in a service instance of a component, then you can set an `*ngIf` with a flag variable on `true` on the loading spinner before it starts and after the response arrives you set the variable to false:

HTML

```
<ng4-loading-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></ng4-loading-spinner>
```

TS:

```
getData() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.httpClient.get(...).subscribe(
    () => { 
      this.isLoading = false;
    } 
  );

}
```